# Configure Atmel MaxTouch Digitizer on Samsung ATIV 6

Tags: kubuntu, display, samsung, touchscreen

I am trying to figure out how to configure the touch screen for my Samsung ATIV 6.  I am running Kubuntu 13.04. It is an `Amtel maXTouch Digitzer`.  It recognizes touch, but it only single clicks. Also, when I have my external monitor attached, it thinks the touch screen spans the both screens.

I found many things that were directed for Wacom touchscreens, but nothing for the Amtel.  I'm very new to linux, and am not even sure where to start looking beyond failed google searches.  I found this result, but [I don't have the files this one mentions](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.freedesktop.xorg/47141).

Here is the output of `xinput list`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:200a       id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:1028       id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer            id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ WebCam SC-10HDP12631N                     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Update 11 Aug 2013:

I do want to clarify, my biggest question is how to get the touch screen to work correctly with and external monitor attached.  If I touch the right side of the touch screen, the cursor thinks I am actually touching the external monitor. I mainly want to know how to make the system know the touch screen isn't stretched to the external monitor when it is plugged in.

This is the output to the commands requested below:

`lsinput`

```
/dev/input/event0
   bustype : BUS_HOST
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x5
   version : 0
   name    : "Lid Switch"
   phys    : "PNP0C0D/button/input0"
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_SW

/dev/input/event1
   bustype : BUS_HOST
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x1
   version : 0
   name    : "Power Button"
   phys    : "PNP0C0C/button/input0"
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_KEY

/dev/input/event2
   bustype : BUS_HOST
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x1
   version : 0
   name    : "Power Button"
   phys    : "LNXPWRBN/button/input0"
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_KEY

/dev/input/event3
   bustype : BUS_I8042
   vendor  : 0x1
   product : 0x1
   version : 43841
   name    : "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
   phys    : "isa0060/serio0/input0"
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_KEY EV_MSC EV_LED EV_REP

/dev/input/event4
   bustype : BUS_USB
   vendor  : 0x46d
   product : 0xc52b
   version : 273
   name    : "Logitech Unifying Device. Wirele"
   phys    : "usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2:2"
   uniq    : ""
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_KEY EV_REL EV_ABS EV_MSC EV_LED EV_REP

/dev/input/event5
   bustype : BUS_USB
   vendor  : 0x46d
   product : 0xc52b
   version : 273
   name    : "Logitech Unifying Device. Wirele"
   phys    : "usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2:3"
   uniq    : ""
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_KEY EV_REL EV_MSC

/dev/input/event6
   bustype : BUS_HOST
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x6
   version : 0
   name    : "Video Bus"
   phys    : "LNXVIDEO/video/input0"
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_KEY

/dev/input/event7
   bustype : BUS_HOST
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x6
   version : 0
   name    : "Video Bus"
   phys    : "LNXVIDEO/video/input0"
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_KEY

/dev/input/event8
   bustype : BUS_USB
   vendor  : 0x3eb
   product : 0x8816
   version : 273
   name    : "Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer"
   phys    : "usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5/input0"
   uniq    : ""
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_KEY EV_ABS

/dev/input/event9
   bustype : (null)
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x0
   version : 0
   name    : "HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
   phys    : "ALSA"
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_SW

/dev/input/event10
   bustype : (null)
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x0
   version : 0
   name    : "HDA Intel PCH Mic"
   phys    : "ALSA"
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_SW

/dev/input/event11
   bustype : (null)
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x0
   version : 0
   name    : "HDA Intel PCH Headphone"
   phys    : "ALSA"
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_SW

/dev/input/event12
   bustype : BUS_I8042
   vendor  : 0x2
   product : 0xe
   version : 0
   name    : "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
   phys    : "isa0060/serio1/input0"
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_KEY EV_ABS

/dev/input/event13
   bustype : BUS_USB
   vendor  : 0x2232
   product : 0x1045
   version : 89
   name    : "WebCam SC-10HDP12631N"
   phys    : "usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.4/button"
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_KEY
```

`evtest /dev/input/event8`

```
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x3eb product 0x8816 version 0x111
Input device name: "Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 330 (BTN_TOUCH)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value   3355
      Min        0
      Max     4095
      Resolution      12
    Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
      Value   1550
      Min        0
      Max     4095
      Resolution      21
    Event code 47 (ABS_MT_SLOT)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max       15
    Event code 48 (ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max      255
      Resolution      10
    Event code 49 (ABS_MT_TOUCH_MINOR)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max      255
      Resolution      10
    Event code 52 (ABS_MT_ORIENTATION)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max        1
    Event code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max     4095
      Resolution      12
    Event code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max     4095
      Resolution      21
    Event code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max    65535
    Event code 60 (?)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max     4095
      Resolution      12
    Event code 61 (?)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max     4095
      Resolution      21
Properties:
  Property type 1 (INPUT_PROP_DIRECT)
```

Here is some of the sample data when I touch the screen with `evtest`:

Single touch:

```
Event: time 1376299024.902314, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 23
Event: time 1376299024.902314, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 292
Event: time 1376299024.902314, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 1678
Event: time 1376299024.902314, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 60 (?), value 292
Event: time 1376299024.902314, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 61 (?), value 1678
Event: time 1376299024.902314, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 48 (ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR), value 1
Event: time 1376299024.902314, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 1
Event: time 1376299024.902314, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 292
Event: time 1376299024.902314, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 1678
Event: time 1376299024.902314, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1376299024.959259, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
Event: time 1376299024.959259, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 0
Event: time 1376299024.959259, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

Two fingers:

```
Event: time 1376299060.941027, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1376299065.006084, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 25
Event: time 1376299065.006084, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 409
Event: time 1376299065.006084, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 1227
Event: time 1376299065.006084, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 60 (?), value 409
Event: time 1376299065.006084, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 61 (?), value 1227
Event: time 1376299065.006084, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 1
Event: time 1376299065.006084, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 409
Event: time 1376299065.006084, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 1227
Event: time 1376299065.006084, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1376299065.043034, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 47 (ABS_MT_SLOT), value 1
Event: time 1376299065.043034, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 26
Event: time 1376299065.043034, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 457
Event: time 1376299065.043034, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 2799
Event: time 1376299065.043034, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 60 (?), value 457
Event: time 1376299065.043034, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 61 (?), value 2799
Event: time 1376299065.043034, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1376299065.114060, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 47 (ABS_MT_SLOT), value 0
Event: time 1376299065.114060, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
Event: time 1376299065.114060, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 457
Event: time 1376299065.114060, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 2799
Event: time 1376299065.114060, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1376299065.122075, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 47 (ABS_MT_SLOT), value 1
Event: time 1376299065.122075, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
Event: time 1376299065.122075, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 0
Event: time 1376299065.122075, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out how to map the correct the touchscreen to the screen correctly by using:

```
xinput map-to-output <device> <output name>
```

To find the device id, use

```
xinput list
```

and to find the screen name, use

```
xrandr
```

I just have to find out how to trigger this automatically when the external monitor is connected. You can also make a little script to get the right device id and run the command.

For the click problem, I think multi-touch is recognized for me, I can use 3 fingers to resize and move windows, but even single click does not work sometimes for me. I tap to click, but it behaves as I've just moved the cursor, not actually clicked. Strangely, this happens sometimes, and I don't know what makes it start and stop.

(Found the solution on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchscreen)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure you hardware claims to support multiple touches.

I'm not sure what you want to use the touch screen for but in Ubuntu there isn't many applications that actually support [Xinput2.2 multi-touch protocol](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/multi-touch-protocol.txt).

So lets get the touch screen working.

**lsinput**

You'll probably have to download this one, once you've done that you'll be able to produce an output of all your generic input event devices providing input through the evdev layer. Get this output and write down the location of your Atmel touch device

```
sudo lsinput
```

**evtest**

evtest allows us to check what events your device is pushing into the evdev layer. You'll have to download this one too and then run it on the device location you wrote down earlier

```
evtest /dev/input/eventxx
```

The output of this will tell you what kind of events you're creating from multi-touch. For true multi touch you want to be creating events such as:

```
ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID
ABS_MT_POSITION_X
ABS_MT_POSITION_Y
```

These are your true multi-touch events, if you dont see these then you aren't going to be able to run Ubuntu Multi-touch applications.

if you see the following events you're probably only simulating mouse movements.

```
ABS_X
ABS_Y
```

**MultiTouch Applications**

There is only a handfull of applications that support multi-touch in Ubuntu. I'm not going to explain how to set them up and run them but i'll give you the names of some frameworks to do more research on.

Kivy - Supports multi-touch at the evdev layer. A Python application framework with many example apps and games

Qt - A large application development framework, has limited gesture support but allows development of rich touch UIs.

libAVG - Haven't really used this one but has a selection of great example apps you can run and play with.

edit: Things may not work flawlessly, thats expected but these tools will help identify the issue. Post back the output of any of these commands and I'll help interpret them

Comment: I have edited the original question to include what you asked for.